# Make an Interface constructable in the MainViewModel InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, interface, prism

I am trying to create an Interface called `IService` and have an instance of it created in the constructor of my `MainViewModel`, similar to how we pass `IRegionManager` in prism, i.e like this:

```
public MainViewModel(IService service, IRegionManager regionManager)
{
    _service = service;
    _regionManager = regionManager;
}
```

However, when I go to run the code I get an error as follows: `InvalidOperationException: The current type, IService , is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?`

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong as I've seen this created as intended before. Any ideas?

Comment: how and where you injecting `IService` implementation ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I'm not injecting it anywhere, that I'm aware of. I've got the IService in the Infrastructure project of my Prism solution and then reference the Infrastructure in my module.

Comment: should be some `BootStrapper` for container registration and defining dependency graph.

Comment: Thank you @RahulAgarwal, after looking around for what you are referring to, I found the solution. I've added it below as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to Rahul's comment, I found the solution. I needed to 'register' the interface to the type in the 'InitializeShell' of my project

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    Container.RegisterType<IService, Service>();
}
```

Comment: Rather put that in `ConfigureContainer`

Comment: Oh brilliant. I've made that change now. Thank you @Haukinger.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably instantiating the interface  using `new IService()` or so, but you have to instantiate an object of some class implementing IService and then store it in an IService variable